# Find the count of duplicate continuous subarray

Tags: python, algorithm

I am recently trying to solve some problems from leetcode/codesignal by myself to practice algorithms.. However, I usually got stuck. Leetcode has a discussion and solution section. While there is no answer in codesignal. I got stuck by the below problem from codesignal:

You are given an array of integers arr. Ur task is to count the number of contiguous subarrays such that each element of the subarray appears at least twice.

Example: for arr = [0,0,0], the output should be 3.
there are 3 subarrays that satisfy the criteria:
arr[0..1] = [0,0]
arr[1..2] = [0,0]
arr[0..2] = [0,0,0]

Another Example: for arr = [1,2,1,2,3], the output should be 1.
there is only one applicable subarray:
arr[0..3] = [1,2,1,2]

(I have no idea. stuck by 1 and half hours. I used a hashmap to count the number and the number's frequency. not sure if it's useful... no direction at all)

Anyone can give some help? If you can code on Python would be much more helpful for me. (I can understand JAVA a bit. but no C++ or other language)

Comment: How large is arr?

Comment: You can see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-subarrays-having-each-distinct-element-occuring-at-least-twice/)

Comment: hello learning mathematics. there are many test cases. some are length of 5 like the example I showed, some are up to 2000 or more

Comment: hello bb1. thank you. but it's not the same. I've seen the one you sent before actually. That one if find repeats at least twice. but this one requires certain pattern and it needs to be continuous

Comment: What is the maximum size of `arr`? Is O(n^2) solution expected to pass?

Comment: The problem provided by @bb1 is identical to the problem you mentioned as far as I can see. Subarrays are always contiguous.

Comment: yes! o(n^2) is acceptable!

Comment: @LearningMathematics I see. Yes. They are the same problem... Thank you!